# Will point M act as a centre of circle, and if yes. Why?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, triangle-centres

[image]

I've gotten around this problem. But fail to understand why point M will act as a centre in this problem? If NM is perpendicular to M, how does it ensures that point M will be the centre? Because the closer point M move towards I, the distance between N and M increases. So, how exactly it is deduced to be a centre?

Comment: What exactly is $\square KING$? A square? A rectangle? A general quadrilateral?

Comment: A general quadrilateral. If you draw it out, the figure is that of a cyclic quadrilateral.

Comment: If KING is cyclic quadilateral with fixed diameter of circumcircle $D$ and the distance GI is fixed as $d$, then MN is not greater than $\frac{D}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{D^2-d^2}}{2}$. Maximum value corresponds to case when M is middle of GI.

Comment: The problem with your condition is that it is not full. **Maximum posiible** at which conditions? How general quadrilateral is? If it is general quadrilateral and we know only two numbers that are given in text (AM and GI), the MN length is not bounded.